# How do I make text in Pyglet's ScrollableTextLayout scroll upwards, rather than down? .view_y doesn't seem to have the effect listed in the docs

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to figure out how to make text scroll upwards in Pyglet's ScrollableTextLayout, rather than down. For sake of clarity, here's a quick snapshot to show what I mean by "up." (Just in case)

[image: How it currently behaves]

How I would like it to behave:

[image]

According to the docs, this behavior can be achieved via the view_y property, but I've tried all kinds of different values, but all with no noticeable change.

The code:

```
import pyglet

class LoadDialog(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lbatch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        self.loading_window = pyglet.image.load('..\\resources\\loading_base.png')
        super(LoadDialog, self).__init__(self.loading_window, batch=self.lbatch)


        self.doc = pyglet.text.decode_text('Hello world!'.ljust(40))
        self.doc.set_style(0,12, dict(font_name='Arial', font_size=12,
                                    color=(0,0,0,255)))

        self.layout = pyglet.text.layout.ScrollableTextLayout(self.doc, 
                                            width=self.load_animation.width, 
                                            height=100, multiline=True, batch=self.lbatch)
        self.layout.x = 220
        self.layout.y = 160
        self.layout.view_y = -80

    def update(self, dx):
        self.doc.insert_text(0, "New line".ljust(40))






sprite = LoadDialog()
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=640, height=480)

pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.lbatch.draw()
    sprite.layout.draw()

@window.event
def update(dx):
    sprite.update(dx)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0)
pyglet.app.run()
```

I've tried tons of values for `layout.view_y`, from `-1` to absurd values like `-3000`, or `500` just to see if *something* changes. But it always gives the exact behavior as shown in the first image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now that's how you ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, your example depends on an image file and its width *(not provided)*, which complicated testing slightly.

**Second**, you are creating an [UnformattedDocument](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.document.UnformattedDocument-class.html) by calling [pyglet.text.decode_text](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text-module.html#decode_text), and then you repeatedly insert text into the [UnformattedDocument](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.document.UnformattedDocument-class.html) explicitly at position 0 (the start) on this line:

```
def update(self, dx):
    self.doc.insert_text(0, "New line".ljust(40))
```

If you want the text to appear at the end, as you imply in your graphics, insert it at the end!

```
def update(self, dx):
    # Fix the implied bug
    self.doc.insert_text(-1, "New line".ljust(40))
```

**Third**, lets answer your actual stated question.  If you read the API documentation for the property [ScrollableTextLayout.view_y](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.text.layout.ScrollableTextLayout-class.html#view_y) you will find that...

> Values outside of the range [height - content_height, 0] are automatically clipped in range.

...so setting view_y to -80 when content_height is 0, results in view_y getting clipped to 0 and then you never try setting view_y again.  The solution to your scrolling problem is to set view_y each time that your content height changes.  For a simple fix, you could simply set view_y such that the bottom of your content will always be scrolled up to the bottom of your frame:

```
def update(self, dx):
    # Fix the implied bug
    self.doc.insert_text(-1, "New line".ljust(40))
    # The answer to the stated question
    self.layout.view_y = -self.layout.content_height
```